# Simplest grass seed mulch options: Nothing vs Paper vs Ground Wheat vs Ground Oats

Tags: grass, compost, germination, mulch

I am growing Kentucky bluegrass on deep topsoil in Minnesota and found that the grass
punches through mostly in spots covered by a thin shredded-paper mulch that I applied
(since I applied the paper sloppily, I can see that the grass grows mainly through the
paper-covered spots and less so in bare spots).  I am watering it 3 times per day,
with about 1/4 inch of water per time.

So, why does paper mulch help growth?  Is this just helping to retain moisture even
though it seems like I am keeping the ground saturated with water?

Anyway, my real question, since I'm finding that wheat flour and "quick" oats are
somehow even cheaper than paper, what would be the harm in replacing the paper
with these edibles?  My instinct is that grass would grow even better with
a finely-ground wheat or oat covering (which will stay continually moist just like
the paper).  Is the only downside to switching to these edibles that birds and
animals will come eat everything?